# Hidden methods in type implementations?

Tags: go, methods, interface

Going through some go sources in the `net/http` and related libraries, I came across [something](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4ce6a8e89668b87dce67e2f55802903d6eb9110a/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go#L521-L532) that made me curious. I'm looking at version 1.12 here.

```
func (p *ReverseProxy) handleUpgradeResponse(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, res *http.Response) {
  ...
  hj, ok := rw.(http.Hijacker)
  ...
  conn, brw, err := hj.Hijack()
  ...
}
```

I've been seeing stuff like this in more places and also outside the standard library. What is happening here? Are some methods of an interface implementation hidden until a specific assertion happens? Why can't I just call `Hijack()` on the  `rw` object?

Comment: "hidden until a specific cast happens" -- Just a note: Go doesn't do casting at all, so this cannot be the explanation :)

Comment: Changed "cast" to "assertion", I agree this is not casting. But how would you call `bs := []byte("Hello world")`? Isn't that casting of a string to a slice of bytes?

Comment: No, it's not a casting. It's a type conversion. Read about the difference [here](https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-type-casting-and-type-conversion.html) if it's unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods appear to be hidden, because the function takes an interface type. The interface of `http.ResponseWriter` does not define the `Hijack()` method. This is defined in the `http.Hijacker` interface. A concrete type may implement multiple interfaces. But even if such concrete type is passed into a scope where its type definition is an interface, additional methods will not be accessible. So in the questioned example, type assertion is performed to make make the `Hijack()` method available.

Some examples ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jMBenb642OB)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Ship interface {
    Load(containers []string)
    Condition() []string
}

type Sea interface {
    Draft() int
}

// seaShip implements the Sea and Ship interfaces
type seaShip struct {
    containers []string
}

// Load is only part of the Ship interface
func (ss *seaShip) Load(containers []string) {
    ss.containers = append(ss.containers, containers...)
}

// Condition is only part of the Ship interface
func (ss *seaShip) Condition() []string {
    return ss.containers
}

// Draft is only part of the Sea interface
func (ss *seaShip) Draft() int {
    return len(ss.containers)
}

// Pirates is not defined in any interface and therefore can only be called on the concrete type
func (ss *seaShip) Pirates() string {
    return "Help!"
}

// NewShip returns an implementation of the Ship interface
func NewShip() Ship {
    return &seaShip{}
}

func main() {
    ship := NewShip()
    ship.Load([]string{"Beer", "Wine", "Peanuts"})
    fmt.Println(ship.Condition())
    // Won't compile, method is not part of interface!
    // fmt.Println(ship.Draft())

    // Assert to make Draft() available
    sea := ship.(Sea)
    fmt.Println(sea.Draft())

    // Won't compile, methods are not part of interface!
    // fmt.Println(sea.Condition())
    // fmt.Println(sea.Pirates())

    // Assert to the concrete type makes all methods available
    ss := sea.(*seaShip)
    fmt.Println(ss.Condition())
    fmt.Println(ss.Pirates())
}
```